# Как преобразовать class code(object) в строку и обратно

Tags: python

```
import marshal
f = open('c:\\test.pyc', 'rb').read()
c = marshal.loads(f[8:])
```

Извиняюсь за банальный вопрос.
Как преобразовать "с" в str. Затем из строки обратно в изначальное значение.

Comment: Можете уточнить, что именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Хочу передать загруженный marshal.loads код в строке по сети